# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol and Enhanced e-commerce not capturing revenue

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm trying to use the measurement protocol to record an offline purchase on our backend system. The problem is, after I send the Measurement Protocol request, the goal conversion is captured correctly in GA's reports, but the revenue earned from the purchase is always displayed as 0.00 in the reports, even though I am sending a value of 500.00 in the revenue parameter.

Here is the request I am sending to the measurement protocol:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
v=1
&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXXX
&cid=XXXXXXX.XXXXXX
&uid=123
&t=pageview
&dh=http://example.com
&dp=order/thank_you
&dt=thank+you
&ti=127210
&ta=offline+conversion
&tr=500.00
&pa=purchase
&pr1id=1864
&pr1nm=Abc+Program
&pr1ca=Software
&pr1pr=500.00
&cu=CNY
&sc=end
&aip=1
```

The next day, when I check GA's Conversions reports, the goal conversion is tracked successfully, but the e-commerce report always displays the revenue earned for this purchase as 0.00, even though I've specified the price to be 500.00 in the request.  I've already tried the following tasks to resolve the problem, but to no avail:

1. Double-check that Enhanced E-commerce is enabled in GA (it is).
2. Change &t=pageview to &t=transaction, but this modification results in neither the goal nor the revenue to be captured in GA.
3. Re-constructed the request in Google's [Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) and validated the hit (it is valid)
4. Sent the request to /debug/collect to validate the hit (it is valid). Below is the response:

   ```
    "hitParsingResult": [ {
       "valid": true,
       "parserMessage": [ {
         "messageType": "INFO",
         "description": "IP Address from this hit was anonymized to 106.111.63.0.",
         "messageCode": "VALUE_MODIFIED"
       } ],
       "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X\u0026cid=XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX\u0026uid=123\u0026t=pageview\u0026dh=http%253A%252F%252Fmydomain.com\u0026ti=127210\u0026ta=offline%20conversion\u0026tr=500.00\u0026pa=purchase\u0026pr1id=1864\u0026pr1nm=Abc%20Program\u0026pr1ca=Software\u0026pr1pr=500.00\u0026cu=CNY\u0026sc=end\u0026aip=1"
     } ],
     "parserMessage": [ {
       "messageType": "INFO",
       "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
     } ]
   ```

Here is the screenshot of the above purchase in GA's conversion reports:

[image]

As shown above, the revenue from the purchase is 0.00, even though the revenue I sent to GA is 500.00.

Any idea why Google is not tracking the revenue?

Would also appreciate any thoughts on how to better troubleshoot this issue... because Google's /debug/collect script is not providing much insight into the problem. Any idea what other approaches to take for troubleshooting this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, found the problem. I didn't include the quantity of product purchased in the request data. In order for revenue to be tracked, you not only have to provide the product price (pr1pr), you also have to provide the product quantity (pr1qt).

So, I added the following parameter into the Measurement Protocol request:

```
&pr1qt=1
```

And now revenue is being tracked successfully.